# IOS Http post when app run background

Tags: ios

I am from android background.. can we do http post every 5 minutes when app runs in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically: yes. It's possible. You can do that on Jailbreak Devices as well as on Enterprise Deployment Aoo.
You can use the [VOIP App Mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html).

If you'd like to deploy the app through the iTunes App Store, you will get a "reject" from apple.
Background-Apps are currently not allowed by apple (only real VOIP apps, Music-In-Background and GPS Tracking Apps).
Know why? Because every app running in background eats a lot of battery power.

Comment: This is why the [Sparrow email client for iPhone](http://sparrowmailapp.com/iphone.php) was initially rejected from the App Store - it used the VOIP mode to check mail in the background, but wasn't a VOIP app.